# Any advice on how to beat Robotnik?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, dr-robotniks-mean-bean-machine

I am having difficulty beating the last level in Dr. Robotnik's Mean Bean Machine. The speed at which the beans fall is way too fast! Is there any advice that someone can give me to actually pass this level?

Comment: Sounds like there may not exist any useful advice; judging by [this thread](https://forums.playfire.com/general-discussion/thread/36220), it sounds like it's a matter of luck and abusing the save system (if that is a feature of the platform).